# Regarding Docker Containerization and Composing Containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have a scenario as we have an application which has three components like:

1. Application Solution
2. API Solution
3. Postgres Database

And we have to configure all this components using docker as:

- Container 1 - Application Solution
- Container 2 - API Solution
- Particular Server - Database

And we need to connect all these together to run the application as:

- Our application is connected to API using localhost on some port
- Our API is connected to database on some server xyz

`Application` --> `API` --> `Database`

We are also facing a major issue with the ports of containers as the host for API and application's container are listening on 8080 only. We have nothing specific in our code where we have defined port as 8080. But API container and Web container internally are running on 8080 only. So, for that reason only our connection between the container is not building.

We are using this docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: energy_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: energyEfficiencydb
  api:
    image: energyefficiencyapi
    container_name: energyefficiencyapi
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__dev=http://database:5432
    depends_on:
      - database

  website:
    image: energyefficiencyportal
    container_name: energyefficiencyportal
    ports: 
      - 8081:8080
    depends_on:
      - api
```

We tried using this compose file but we were unable to build communication between containers.

I also want to configure my postgres data which is deployed on pgadmin on some server and i want to connect it to my API as well.

Comment: Which connection is failing?  How are you trying to make that connection?  Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: No i dont have a specific error message but using a compose file i am doing it as i have created images for both backend and frontend solution .I just want to connect my Forntend application's Container with Backend containers and my application is build in asp.net core 8.0 and also i have not specified any port but my both container are listening on port 8080 and also to be specific i am using windows Docker desktop for the work and i am failing in it